# Simple translator using dict, Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using dict to store a text file with English word first then Spanish word second in columns.

What I want it to do is be able to search a word(English word) and then translate it to Spanish. I'm not sure why this is returning None every time I enter a word to translate.

Im using python3, if that makes a difference.

```
def getDict():
    myDict  = {}

    for line in open("eng2sp.txt"):
       for n in line:
           (eng,span) = line.split()
           myDict[eng] = span


    print("Translate from English to Spanish")
    word = input("Enter the english word to translate:")

    print(search(myDict,word))



def search(myDict,lookup):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        for v in value:
            if lookup in v:
                return



def main():
    getDict()


main()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are using `return` without providing it a value, so it will always return `None`.

Comment: @Brendan Molloy - is that why it returns None? When will that condition ever match? It doesn't match and then the function defaults to returning None. The search function a) looks up the dictionary values (Spanish), then b) looks through every character in the Spanish word, checking to see if c) the English word is contained in one character of the Spanish word. It can't match a word in a character, so it never hits the `return` statement. The function ends after looping through everything. None is the default return value.

Comment: Hmmm.... I remember the name `eng2sp.txt` from my own python homework a long time ago... xD. Anyway, too homework-y for me.

Answer (score 4):

This could be much simpler:

```
def search(myDict,lookup):
    if lookup in myDict:
        return myDict[lookup]
    return "NOT FOUND"
```

This code will give much better performance for large dictionaries. You might want to return `None` instead of a string when the item isn't found, depends how you want to handle that case.

Comment: Thank you! I dont know why I was over complicating my search function.

Comment: The `for key, value in myDict.items():` is fine for things such as printing out the whole dictionary one entry at a time, but not the way to search it.

Comment: `return myDict.get(lookup, 'NOT FOUND')`

Comment: Yes that's an alternative way, but knowing how to lookup in a dictionary with square brackets and the `in` operator are more general purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The search function is really not needed. You can find the translation directly by accessing `my_dict[word]`.

Assuming your text file has entries like:

```
hello hola
goodbye adios
```

then you can use something like this:

```
my_dict = {}

with open('eng2sp.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        eng, span = line.split()
        my_dict[eng] = span


while True:
    word = input('\nEnter english word to translate: ')
    if word == "":
        break
    elif word in my_dict.keys():
        print(my_dict[word])
    else:
        print('Error: word not in dictionary')
```